# R Using Random Forest or SVM

Tags: r, svm, random-forest

## Problem:

**The following code is to predict the last row's price
using all previous rows as a training set**
** The prediction is very nice when the last row price smaller than 10, but becomes
unreasonable when the test price gets bigger.
** Same problem happens using SVM package

```
file <- read.csv('test.csv',head=F)

N<-nrow(file)
train <- file[1:N-1,]
test <- file[N,]

forest <- randomForest(train[,1] ~., data = train)
rf.predict <- predict(forest, newdata=test)

rf.predict  #10.08446
```

data:

```
       V1     V2     V3
1     3.0    1.0    2.0
2    -6.0   -6.2   -6.2
3   -30.2  -31.2  -30.7
4    -2.1   -1.3   -1.8
5   -11.4   -9.5  -10.7
6     8.4    8.8    8.6
7     6.3    6.5    6.4
8    -0.2    3.2    1.5
9    -8.8  -10.2   -9.3
10  -10.2  -11.0  -10.7
11  -16.3  -15.6  -16.0
12   -2.5   -2.5   -2.5
13  -17.2  -16.7  -16.8
14   10.4   10.0   10.2
15   -3.0   -5.3   -4.0
16    2.1    3.5    2.5
17   -2.0   -1.4   -1.5
18   11.7   12.2   11.8
19   11.2   11.2   11.2
20   -1.0   -0.4   -0.9
21    3.8    1.9    3.2
22   -9.3  -10.7   -9.7
23  -17.7  -15.7  -17.5
24 1000.5 1000.0 1001.0
```

Comment: is this a question ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect a (highly flexible) model to do well when extrapolating to this degree. Trying to predict on values that are a couple of orders of magnitude larger than anything in your training data is kind of silly.

Comment: I wanna know what fundamental reason behind it causes this result? With 1000 as test set, should the prediction be at least closer to 1000 than 10?

Comment: @Kun No. See Gavin Simpson's answer.

Comment: This is OT for [so]. I have flagged to get it migrated to CrossValidated

Answer (score 8):

If you have no training data even remotely close to the test data then RF cannot hope to predict it with any degree of accuracy. This stems from the way in which RF's work - which is how tree models work. The predicted value from a single tree for an observation is the mean value of the response variable of all the training set samples in the node of the tree to which the predicted sample is assigned. RFs extend this to many trees (so you average over $n$ trees, not just 1) and involve bagging and random selection of variables for each split. But the fundamental feature is an average of the training samples most similar to the predicted sample. Hence you can only operate within the range of the observed response data.